# Swift launch app when applicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I wanna launch my app when plugged-in on iOS devices but i don't find any solution how can i do it. I wonder, does Apple allow launching application in applicationWillTerminate function?

Thanks for your interest.

Regards.

Comment: please try elaborate your question, it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

> This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and purged from memory entirely.
>
> Source: [API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate)

`applicationWillTerminate:` tells you that you app needs to be killed by the system. Since this won't happen just for fun, Apple won't allow you to restart the app automatically ;-)

Apart from that, I think there is no (public) function at all, that allows you to launch an app programmatically.